# No cookie generated using fetch API on SignIn using cookie authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have method in my AccountController the should be called via a POST request. This method just looks up a user based on the passed credentials and signs in the user using cookie authentication. The AccountController looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    var data = new
    {
        Success = false
    };

    // Removed some code for brevity

    await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync(HttpContext, BuildClaims(company.Id, model.Username), BuildAuthenticationProperties());

    return Json(new
    {
        success = true
    });
}
```

I've removed some code to make it short but basically, it just signs in the user.

Now I am calling this method with an AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ajax-submit").click(function () {

        var data = {
            companyCode: "TC",
            username: "username",
            password: "password"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/Login",
            method: "POST",
            data: data
        })
        .done(function () {
            window.location.href = "/";
        });         

    });
});
```

On success, it creates the cookie and I can redirect to the correct page. Now I wanted to use fetch, so I replaced the jQuery AJAX call with this one:

```
fetch("/Account/Login", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
        if (data.success) {
            window.location.href = "/";
        }
        else {                      
        }
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

It signs in successfully on the AccountController but my problem is no cookie is generated so I am not allowed access to the secured page (with Authorized attribute). Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SignInManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0) class to sign the user in or out. The [`PasswordSignInAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_PasswordSignInAsync__0_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) takes an `isPersistent` argument which when set to `true` sets a persistent cookie.

Here's a simple example usage:

```
[HttpPost, Route("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginViewModel model)
{
    // Validate the vm here
    // Perform the login
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username,
                                                              model.Password,
                                                              isPersistent: true,
                                                              lockoutOnFailure: true);

    // Check if the account was locked
    // or if 2FA is required for the user
    // and handle it accordingly 

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I did not mention but I do not want to use ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: @g_b what's the rationale behind not using ASP.NET Identity? What else are you using?

Comment: The project is for my learning only, I wanted to learn how to create a user authorization module without ASP.NET Identity.